# JavaScript: How to use a method within a prototype?

Tags: javascript, pikaday

I am trying to modify a plug-in (Pikaday) and add my own little bit of functionality.

The plugin is built using the proto-type system, and I have added my funciton within it.

```
Pikaday.prototype = {

   //OTHER PARTS OF PLUGIN

  showYearPicker: function()
        {
            document.getElementsByClassName('pika-year-label').onclick=function(){
                console.log("asfd");
            }
        }, 

    //OTHER PARTS OF PLUGIN
}

return Pikaday;
```

What I am having trouble understanding is how to actually trigger this method. Clicking the specified element doesnt work.

Would anyone know how I can include this function as part of the plugin?

[Full code](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday/blob/master/pikaday.js) (minus my addition) is here if anyone is interested.

Comment: @4castle no, I am not. I thought I should but this confused me as other functions within the prototype are not called. I thought all functions withthin the prototype were called automatically

Comment: You need to add the `onclick` listener in a loop. `getElementsByClassName` returns a list, not a single element. (And no, prototype functions aren't called automatically. They still have to be called with `new Pikaday().showYearPicker()`)

Comment: getElementsByClass name returns a NodeList. You can't assign the onclick to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a method on the prototype of a function in simple terms means you've defined a method on an object that will be one link up the prototype chain from all instances of this function.

You can think of it as a common "parent" or "object-above" for every instance of that function.

Therefore, to use your method, you must instantiate the plugin and call your function on it.

```js
function Pikaday() {}

Pikaday.prototype = {

  showYearPicker: function() {
    console.log('called');
  }
}

let pikaday = new Pikaday();
pikaday.showYearPicker(); // <-- call the function on the prototype
```

What this will do is check if `pikaday` has `showYearPicker` defined on it, and since it doesn't, it will go up the proto chain and check if that object has it, which it does.

In other words, this is essentially what the JS engine does behind the scenes:

```
let pikaday = new Pikaday();
pikaday.__proto__.showYearPicker();
```

Note that [**proto**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) here is just for demonstration, its only recently been standardized in ES6 for legacy purposes, but this behavior should be left to the JS engine (The [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) calls this proto link `[[Prototype]]`).

If needed, the proper way to access the prototype is to use [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) (in +ES6 you could use the semantically-clearer [Reflect.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/getPrototypeOf))

```js
function Pikaday() {}

console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(new Pikaday()) === Pikaday.prototype
);

console.log(
  Reflect.getPrototypeOf(new Pikaday()) === Pikaday.prototype
);
```

One problem with your code is that [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) will return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (not an array) of nodes that have this class.

This means you must either loop over this list and attach a handler to each element,

```
let nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('pika-year-label');
Array.from(nodes) // convert NodeList to an array so we can use forEach
  .forEach(node => {
    // attach a handler on each node
    node.onclick = function (){
      console.log("asfd");
    }
  });

// Side Note: You can also use array spread to convert the node list to an array
// [...nodes].forEach( ... )
```

or alternatively attach a handler to a common parent for all the elements to delegate the behavior.

```
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('pika-year-label')) {
    console.log("asfd");
  }
}
```

Finally, if you only want to add this function to an existing function's prototype, one way to do it is to simply define it as a method on that prototype:

```js
function Pikaday() {}

// define a method on the existing prototype
Pikaday.prototype.showYearPicker = function() {
  console.log('called');
};

let pikaday = new Pikaday();
pikaday.showYearPicker(); // <-- call the function on the prototype
```

Comment: Actually `__proto__` is deprecated. [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) is the recommended standard.

Comment: That is the correct way to obtain the prototype but __proto__ was added to the standard as of ES6

Comment: Thank you for putting in the time to write such a detailed reply :)

Comment: No problem mate, glad to help :)